# C++ Error “Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" "_CFRelease" on Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

I am new to c++. When I build my main.cpp on Xcode, I got this message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CFRelease", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
      print_attributes(IDeckLink*) in main.o
      print_output_mode(char const*, unsigned int, IDeckLinkDisplayMode*, IDeckLinkOutput*) in main.o
      print_input_mode(char const*, unsigned int, IDeckLinkDisplayMode*, IDeckLinkInput*) in main.o
  "_CFStringGetCString", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
      print_attributes(IDeckLink*) in main.o
      print_output_mode(char const*, unsigned int, IDeckLinkDisplayMode*, IDeckLinkOutput*) in main.o
      print_input_mode(char const*, unsigned int, IDeckLinkDisplayMode*, IDeckLinkInput*) in main.o
  "_CreateDeckLinkIteratorInstance", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
```

I researched on stackoverflow and found Alex Reche Martinez suggested adding "-framework CoreFoundation" to the link command line of the project. But I don't know which file contains the link command line. Can anyone help? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should find it in the project settings dialog.

Comment: Actually, I just found how to solve this issue. Click on the top level of the project name in Xcode to view all the configuration/settings for this project. Under General, click on Linked Frameworks and Libraries, click on the "+" sign will allow you open the "Choose frameworks and libraries" dialogue. Scroll down to find "CoreFoundation.framework" and click on Add.